# Setting Rating Column As Computed vs Updating Every Time

Tags: sql-server, performance, database-design, calculated-columns

I have a `table` named `Companies` where there is a `Rating column`. Company has many reviews and which has its `Rating` column.

**Companies.Rating = Average of its Reviews' Ratings**.
My question: It'll be easier for me `Companies.Rating` to be computed instead of it to be updated when Company review is deleted, inserted, updated etc.

Will it slow down the app. seriously ?
P.S. each company will have about 300 reviews.(maximum)

Comment: Compute it until you encounter an actual performance issue.

Comment: Agree with Andomar.  300 reviews and an aggregate shouldn't be a big deal.

Comment: How are you going to compute it? A [computed column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250(v=sql.105).aspx) can only reference columns in the same table, so you can't put a computed column on the `Companies` table to show a value calculated from the `Reviews` table (if that was your idea, it's a bit unclear). You could use a [function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769007/formula-for-computed-column-based-on-different-tables-column) but a view might be a better (simpler) idea here.

Comment: Yes, @Pondlife I've created a function which returns average rating for a single company. What do mean by creating view?