# SQL Server - GROUP BY with HAVING on more than 10 million rows hitting performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-performance

SQL Server - how to improve query performance with GROUP BY and with HAVING clause of 30 + OR conditions on More than 10 million rows

Comment: indexing is the best way for performance, also see the Execution Plan from SQL server Management studio to see where is taking much time.

Comment: Take a breath and think about what got you into such a position :)

Comment: Consider using an indexed view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can be more helpful if you show us your query (you can obfuscate it if you need), but generically you can create computed, persisted, bit columns that pre-calculate the OR statements for you:

https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2016/04/27/sql-server-computed-column-conditions-case-statement/

Instead of:

```
HAVING [A] > 100000 OR [B] < 1000
```

Use:

```
ALTER TABLE [FOO]
ADD IsFiltered AS CASE WHEN [A] > 100000 OR [B] < 1000 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END PERSISTED
```

And then add [IsFiltered] to an index for extra speed. You can also create functions to perform calculations for you:

[formula for computed column based on different table's column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769007/formula-for-computed-column-based-on-different-tables-column)

Alternatively, it may be time to bite the bullet and create these calculations in an SSAS cube. That can be a big leap, but cubes can provide a lot of insight into your data.

Comment: considering how bad the question was this is an excellent answer.  Good Job!

Comment: I don't get it.  A computed column cannot calculate an aggregate -- at least efficiently.  If the `having` is on the group by keys, then that filtering should be moved to a `where` clause.

Comment: @GordonLinoff -- I think the point was that if there are calculation to be used in the "condidtions" they can be pre-calculated for each row to save time during the group by step.

Comment: @Hogan . . . Computed columns are not available after the `GROUP BY`.  Having computed columns only referenced there is not going to be much help.