# Average column values and show the output in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some products in a table `tbProduct` which has these columns:

- Pcode
- product
- Avg_costprice

And I have another table which its name is `tbStockIn` and it has these columns:

- Pcode
- Product
- Cost-price

How can I take the average of the column `Cost-price` according to `Pcode`, and show the output in the column `Avg_costprice`?

Please help me.

Comment: My advice to you as a begineer: please post some a sample of input and output data. It's important to be able to communicate a "repro" (repoduction) of your issue.

Comment: I'm not sure whether I understand what you mean or not. Do you want to insert data in `Product` table related to data that exist in `Stock` table?

Comment: @neginmotalebi I want to make the average of  data exists in a column in [Stock] table and insert the output of the average in [Product] table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to update `Avg_costprice` of `tbProduct` related to `tbStockIn` use this code:

```
UPDATE tbProduct SET 
Avg_costprice = (SELECT AVG(Cost-price) FROM tbStockIn
WHERE tbStockIn.Pcode = tbProduct.Pcode)
```

I hope it helps you with your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I can see 3 options.

**A.** Don't have `tbProduct`

It seems like you may not need `tbProduct` and you could just ask for `Avg_costprice` when you need it:

```
SELECT 
    Pcode, 
    AVG(Cost-price) AS Avg_costprice
FROM tbStockIn;
```

**B.** Update `tbProduct` every time `tbStockIn` changes

If you have to have `tbProduct` then every time you interact with `tbStockIn` you'll need to update the average price. Upon a change to `tbStockIn` you can:

- update the avg. prices only for the products you modify,
- recalculate the avg-prices for the whole product table.

**C.** Computed column

Please see [formula for computed column based on different table's column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769007/formula-for-computed-column-based-on-different-tables-column).